# bash: Split file in 14 files (awk? split? sed? ...?)

Tags: bash

I will split a file with e.g. 413 lines in 14 files.

```
file_all = 413 lines
file_split_1 = 29 lines or 30 lines
file_split_2 = 29 lines or 30 lines
file_split_2 = 29 lines or 30 lines
:
:
file_split_14 = 36 lines or 23 lines
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you failing?

Comment: that depends any question?

Comment: `man split` could be an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will do the job. Just change the file name with whatever you want and then it will do job.

```
fileNum=14
var=13
totalLines=$(cat file.txt|wc -l)
eachLine=$(expr $totalLines / $fileNum)
finalLine=$(expr $var \* $eachLine)
finalLine=$(expr $totalLines - $finalLine)
tmp=$totalLines
for i in {1..13}
do
fileName=$(echo file$i)
cat file.txt | tail -$tmp | head -$eachLine > $fileName
tmp=$(expr $tmp - $eachLine)
done
cat exam2014.txt | tail -$finalLine | head -$finalLine > file14
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is hopelessly unclear, but perhaps you are looking for something as simple as:

```
awk 'NR%30==1{of++}{print > "file_split_"of}' file_all
```

Comment: what is unclear?? I have a file named file_all with 413 lines and i will split this file in multiple files named file_split_1 / file_split_2 / ... / file_split_14.

Comment: Your question remains horribly unclear.  "You will split the file".Okay, great, so split the file.  What's the question?  Are you asking "How can I split the file?"  Or are you asking, "How can I split the file into 14 files and I don't care if the constituent files end up with 29 or 30 lines each, with the remainder in the 14th file?" Or are you asking "How can I split the file and pseudo-randomly put either 29 or 30 lines in each sub file?"